# Can I create a new numerical variable using dplyr and <= and >= operators to subset values from an existing vector?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a variable that has a very large range of values.  I want to create a new variable in my dataframe that constitutes a subset of those values, with all original values that are not within the specified range for the subset listed as NA.  I have tried to do this with mutate in dplyr but the variable that is being returned is a logical vector.

For example with mtcars, I have tried:

```
test <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(mpg_subset = mpg<=22) %>% 
  mutate(mpg_subset=mpg_subset>=18)
```

Here, I want a new numerical variable called mpg_subset that contains only those values where mpg is <= 22 and >=18, and where all values that are not within these bounds are labelled as NA.

Unfortunately, what I am getting back is a logical vector for mpg_subset that is telling me if the original value for mpg meets these conditions (TRUE or FALSE), rather than a numerical vector.  I also tried using the filter function but got the same result.  I'm new to dplyr so I am not sure what I am doing wrong!

Can anyone advise how I would obtain the data I need?

Thank you so much!

Comment: You say you tried `filter()`. Did you try it like this: `test <- mtcars %>% filter(mpg <= 22 & mpg >= 18)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

an ifelse within the mutate should hopefully do the trick.

```
test <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(mpg_subset = ifelse(mpg<=22 & mpg >=18, mpg, NA))
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  Do you know how I would append that new column to the original dataset?

Comment: `mtcars <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(mpg_subset = ifelse(mpg<=22 & mpg >=18, mpg, NA))`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
test <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(mpg_subset = case_when(between(mpg,18,22) ~ mpg))
```

Answer (score 2):

I know you specified `dplyr`, but if anybody is interested in a `data.table` solution, this uses an `ifelse` statement...

```
as.data.table(mtcars)[, mpg_subset := ifelse(mpg <= 22 & mpg >= 18, mpg, NA)]
```

You could probably do something similar with `dplyr`.

Comment: Or `as.data.table(mtcars)[mpg %between% c(18, 22), mpg_subset := mpg][]`